# How to set focus when using React hook form Controller component

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a CustomTextBox component that is wrapped in react-hook-form Controller component and all works fine including validation and displaying the error message with ErrorMessage component.

The only thing left to-do is to setFocus on the fields when there is errors in the form. This is my first TypeScript project and i'm struggling to find solutions which are similar to mine.

I tried useRef but this only give compile time error =>  "Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes".

Below is my Custom component. Please guys all help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { Control, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { Keys } from '../Profile/interfaces';

interface Props {
  id: string;
  label: string,
  variant: "filled" | "standard" | "outlined", 
  disabled?: boolean,
  control: Control<any,any>
  required?: boolean,
  name: Keys,
  requiredMsg?: string
}

const CustomTextBox: React.FC<Props> = ({id, label, variant,disabled=false, control, 
required=false, name, requiredMsg}) => {
  const inputRef = useRef<React.RefObject<HTMLButtonElement>>();
  return (
    <Controller        
      ref={inputRef}
      name={name}      
      control={control}
      rules={{required: required ? requiredMsg : null}}     
      render={({ field }) =>
        <TextField inputRef={field.ref}  InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }} id={id} label={label} variant={variant} 
         disabled={disabled} {...field}
        style={{marginTop: '10px', marginBottom: '10px', minWidth: '250px'}} /> }
    />
  );
}

export default CustomTextBox;
```

Comment: Did you try moving the "ref" to the "TextField" component instead?

Comment: I get warning about Function components cannot be give refs. But it still doesn't work. Thanks though for your input

Comment: How about using the `field.ref` to set the focus with `field.ref.current.focus()`?

Comment: Hello again....im not quit sure I follow you suggestion ?

Comment: See below response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So thanks to @Victor Luft i was able to get it right with the below code. Also this is not in the component itself but rather on the page/component that uses Custom Components. This will focus on any element that has an error in your react-hook-form form tag. I hope that makes sense.

Thanks again Victor

```
useEffect(() => {               
        const firstErrorKey = Object.keys(errors).find((key) => errors[key]);
    if (firstErrorKey) {
      (document.querySelector(
        `input[name="${firstErrorKey}"]`
      ) as HTMLInputElement | null)?.focus();
    }
  }, [Object.keys(errors)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `field.ref` as `inputRef` for the `TextField` component. It is very likely that this will be assigned to the native `<input />` element. And that is the one, you want to be able to call `focus()` on.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { Control, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { Keys } from '../Profile/interfaces';

interface Props {
  id: string;
  label: string,
  variant: "filled" | "standard" | "outlined", 
  disabled?: boolean,
  control: Control<any,any>
  required?: boolean,
  name: Keys,
  requiredMsg?: string
}

const CustomTextBox: React.FC<Props> = ({id, label, variant,disabled=false, control, 
required=false, name, requiredMsg}) => {
  const inputRef = useRef<React.RefObject<HTMLButtonElement>>();
  return (
    <Controller        
      ref={inputRef}
      name={name}      
      control={control}
      rules={{required: required ? requiredMsg : null}}     
      render={({ field, fieldState }) => {
         // don't know who to compute this state as I don't know this lib
        const hasError = fieldState === 'error';
        if (field.ref.current && fieldState === 'error') field.ref.current.focus();
        return (
          <TextField inputRef={field.ref}  InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }} id={id} label={label} variant={variant} 
         disabled={disabled} {...field}
        style={{marginTop: '10px', marginBottom: '10px', minWidth: '250px'}} />); 
    }}
    />
  );
}

export default CustomTextBox;
```

Comment: I tried your solution but "field.ref" does not have a property called current

Comment: I see. Then maybe create a sandbox example and link it in your question. That would make it easier to debug your issue. I don't want to create the code by myself first.

Comment: Okay I will do so and link it. Thanks I really appreciate your help

Comment: Here is the code sandbox link -  https://sqcpdn.csb.app/

Comment: Good luck....This issue has been grieving me for days

Comment: There are many ways how to solve your problem, but I would rather approach it differently. It seems like you want to set the focus on the input that has currently an error when the user submits. So you find the corresponding element yourself with DOM operations and just focus it. Or you can an effect watching your current error state. Here is an example implemented in the App.tsx: https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-frog-e0t9di?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Hi Again, I have just checkout your sandbox and it looks great. I will now try and reproduce on our application and I'll get back yo you. Thanks again I value your help :)

Comment: Hi....so is does work but only on the first submit. If i make any more changes to any other fields to make the into error state the it does not scroll. However this is a big step forward i will investigate further. It does not seem to enter the useEffect which will change the firstErrorKey.